# Why are buildings shown with a distortion instead of directly from above?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, visualisation, representation

I am pretty new to QGIS so I already am crossing a problem. I opened an open
source map where you can see the buildings. The weird thing is that I see the buildings from an angle instead of directly from above.

Anyone know what the problem may be?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should depend on the Coordinate Reference System (CRS) you are using for your project.

This is one of the very first tasks when working with GIS, so please read [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/coordinate_reference_systems.html#coordinate-reference-systems) for a *gentle introduction* to this topic and [here](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#working-with-projections) for learning how to work with projections in QGIS.

You have probably set a Geographic Coordinate System, which uses degrees as units, while you need to visualize it using a Projected Coordinate System, which uses meters instead.

You should solve the issue by setting a proper projected CRS for the project (you can do this by clicking on the button in the down-right side of the QGIS main window that shows something like *EPSG: ...*) and then, eventually, setting the *On-The-Fly reprojection* if you are using layers with different coordinate reference systems.

Comment: I changed the coordinate system shortly after I wrote my message and it had changed back to normal. But it is interesting to see that meters and units can change things as well